# Why Googletest testsuite summary shows only one testsuite?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am not sure what I missed, I am always getting total testsuite count as one in testsuite summary report. FYI currently I have two testsuite classes.

```
Testsuite summary for testproject
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  1
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

test1.cpp

```
TEST(Testsuite1, Test1)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

test2.cpp

```
TEST(Testsuite2, Test1)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Please show more of test1.cpp and test2.cpp. Are you including <gtest/gtest.h> in both files? Are you using cmake for this? If so what does your CMakeLists.txt look like?

Comment: No I am using automake. Yes I am including gtest.h.

Comment: Are both `test1.cpp` and `test2.cpp` added as sources to the test executable?

Comment: Yes, I have included both the files as source